# How can I pass these Information to Ansible variable?

Tags: mysql, ansible

I sign-up on this site to ask an question.
How can I pass those master status information especially **File** and **Position** to an **Ansible variable**, to automate the processess of replication with an Ansible playbook.

[image: master status]

I want to write this variables in my playbook here.
[image: ansible playbook]

Comment: `CHANGE MASTER` is a rare task; why are you automating it?

Answer (score 1):

**I found some code bit's and wirte my solution.**

```
vars: 
    masterhost: yourlocalhost
    masterip: ip of your host 0.0.0.0

tasks:
    - name: Get data from master file and position 
      mysql_replication:
        mode: getmaster
      register: master1data 

    - name: change master data
      mysql_replication:
        mode: changeprimary
        master_host: '{{ masterip }}'
        master_user: username
        master_password: pass
        master_log_file: '{{ master1data.File }}'
        master_log_pos: '{{ master1data.Position }}'
```